# How to let the scanner stop receiving input?

Tags: java

I am trying to get the sum of the prime digit of an integer, but I cannot stop the scanner from getting input.

Here are my codes.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
    int a = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(Sum(a));
    input.close();
}

public static int Sum(int a) {
    int sum = 0;
    int remainder;
    int remainder2;
    while (a >= 0) {
        remainder = a % 10;
        int prime = Prime(remainder);
        sum += prime;
        a = a / 10;
    }
    return sum;
}

public static int Prime(int remainder) {
    int m = remainder / 2;
    int flag = 0;

    if (remainder != 0 && remainder != 1 && remainder != 2) {
        for (int i = 2; i <= remainder / 2; i++) {
            if (remainder % i == 0) {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (flag == 1) {
        remainder = 0;
    }
    return remainder;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot stop the scanner from getting input"? `int a = input.nextInt();` looks like the only line in your program that reads user input.

Comment: Your loop here `while (a >= 0)` is strange, when do you think `a` will become negative?

Comment: Formatted code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your program is going in an infinite loop before `input.close();` is called.
change the while to stop at >0

```
while (a > 0)
```

and try again.